# A building with an odd elevator

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

In a building, there is an odd elevator, which has only two buttons: UP, which makes it go up 9 floors, and DOWN, which makes it go down 7 floors. (The ground floor is floor 0.) It is possible to reach each floor, but if the building was just *one* floor less tall, this would not be possible anymore. 
How many floors are there in this building?

Comment: (I just made up this puzzle, so bear with me if it is well-known)

Comment: This problem is a variant of the [chicken nugget problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). But congratulations on adding your own little twist!

Comment: @JoeZ.: I thought at that problem, and indeed both of them are based on Euclid's algorithm. However I could not find a natural way to relate their solutions... but probably I should ask in math.SE for help!

Comment: Instead of buying packages of 6 or 9 chicken nuggets, you're buying 9 and *selling* 7 (and you can't have more than 15 at once).

Comment: As phrased, this question leaves ambiguity, since there could be more than one answer.  (15 is an answer, as mentioned below, but so is any $14k + 1$ where $k$ is an integer).

Comment: @JoeZ. Note that the restriction on how many you can have at once is mostly moot, since for any configuration larger than the highest unreachable, you can always arrange your adds and subtracts to not go over the final score.

Comment: @Xynariz: why? Using the algorithm "go down how much you can while you remain above or at floor $f$, otherwise go up" you may reach each floor from $f$ to $f+15$.

Comment: @mau - does the problem require "go down as much as you can"?  I'm not saying [the answer](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/418/11) is wrong, I'm saying that there's more than one right answer.

Comment: @Xynariz: I am not following you. Are you saying that if the building was 28 ( $ = (14\cdot 2 + 1) - 1 $ ) floors high it would not have been possible to reach each floor?

Comment: @mau Correct, for the same reasons you can't visit all floors in a 14-floor building.

Comment: Pardon me. Do you agree that in a 28-floor building I may reach any floor from 0 to 15? If this is the case, what can stop me from arriving to floor 13 and then perform the same algorithm to reach any floor from 13 to 13+15?

Comment: @mau you are right - There can be no valid answer over 28, since you can always go up to 28 and down back to 1, so you can repeat this process for any X >= 28 until you are at Floor = X-15 and just do the solution for 15.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is 15:

```
15             --v
14             . .           --v
13         --v . .           . .
12         . . . .       --v . .
11     --v . . . .       . . . .
10     . . . . . .   --v . . . .
9  --v . . . . . .   . . . . . .
8  . . . . . . . --v . . . . . .
7  . . . . . . .   . . . . . . --
6  . . . . . --^   . . . . . .
5  . . . . .       . . . . --^
4  . . . --^       . . . .
3  . . .           . . --^
2  . --^           . .
1  .               --^
0  ^
```

An intuitive explanation for this is that you can only go two floors *up* at a time, and you have to get above floor 6 to go down and reach an odd numbered floor. But every time you go up by two, you also travel to the floor 7 floors above that one. Therefore, the minimum amount of floors for this to work is `[smallest even number > 6] + 7`, which is `8+7=15`.

By the same logic, a general formula can be constructed, where `n` = the greater number (9) and `m` is the lesser:

$$\text{[smallest number > m divisible by n-m]} + m$$

From which this slightly easier formula can be made:

$$m - (m \text{ mod } (n-m)) + (n-m) + m$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$m + n - (m \text{ mod } (n-m))$$

Comment: just a note: knowing that British and American buildings start at a different floor, I stated that ground floor is 0, so the answer is 15 :-) Besides, the formula I found is much simpler!

Comment: @mau Heh, that would have been good to know. :-P edited